# WildFlyDataSource cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, orm

I am trying to select from a table into my POJO called Product.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Product implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="id", nullable=false)
private int id;

@Column(name="description", nullable=false)
private String description;

@Column(name="image", nullable=false)
private String image;

@Column(name="quantity", nullable=false)
private int quantity;
```

The persistence.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="Product" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <!-- Persistence provider -->
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:/MySqlDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <!-- Entity classes -->
    <class>com.shoppingwebsite.objects.Product</class>
    <properties>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
       <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/MySqlDS"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And the code to select is

```
EntityTransaction transaction = null;
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        EntityManagerFactory emf = (EntityManagerFactory) initialContext.lookup("java:/MySqlDS");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

However

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = (EntityManagerFactory) initialContext.lookup("java:/MySqlDS");
```

gives me exception

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
```

I know I am doing really wrong here, but can someone please point it out?
I really need to select the data directly into Product. The other way is to use DataSource and get a Connection and run a simple query, but I do not want to go that route.

Comment: You are retrieving a data source and think it is an `EntityManagerFactory`, it isn't.

Comment: @Mark Can you please suggest me correct code?

Comment: Change the value of `jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name` to something other than `java:/MySqlDS`, because that name is already used by your data source.